# Fixed Positioning cuts off image, when browser is too small

Tags: css, scroll, positioning, css-position

I have a page where I want to run a long image along the right hand column, halfway down the page.  There is a header on the page, before the content, which pushes this image down about 300px. I'm using fixed positioning to allow the image to follow users, as they scroll down the page.

This works fine until I use a browser which is smaller in size and cuts off the bottom of the image.  As I scroll down the page, the image still follows me, but remains always cut off, even though with the header out of view, there should be enough room to accommodate it.

Is there any way to position this to remain fixed as I scroll, BUT to align it to the top of the browser when scrolling down?

All I have is this right now.  I'm still wrapping my head around css, and just can't find a solution to it:

```
<div id="right_image" style="margin-top:0; position:fixed; width:150px; height:700px; display:block; border:none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify `bottom:0px` (or another value) then it will always stay fixed to the bottom of the page and won't be cut off at the bottom.

EDIT -- add the following script to the page to do what was discussed in the comments (you can remove the jquery reference if you've already got it):

```
<script language='javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop()==0) $('#right_image').css('bottom', '');
        else $('#right_image').css('bottom', '0px');
    });
</script>
```

let me know if this works

Comment: True, but then my 700px tall image is pushed into my header.  :(  I need it to hang out below the header initially, then find it's way to the top of the page as I scroll down.

Comment: Ok I'll write up some jquery that should achieve this and do an edit

Comment: Oh man, this is awesome!!  It jumps over the head just a little bit when I start to scroll, but then works just perfectly!!  I think this will be just fine!!  :)  Thank you SO much!!!

Comment: if you want to tweak it so it doesn't overlap the head, you could change the part that says if($(this).scrollTop()==0) to if($(this).scrollTop()<10) or something, and replace 10 with different numbers until it's just right.